# $3$ people needs $3$ hours to complete $3$ houses. How long for $7$ people to complete $7$ houses?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Suppose that $3$ people require $3$ hours to complete $3$ houses. Assume that they work independently. How much time is required for $7$ people to complete $7$ houses?

I try to apply variation technique to solve the problem, i.e. determine relationship among quantities (people, houses and time). But I couldn't formulate an equation to solve the questions.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: The simple approach is to let the three people work in parallel.  Each builds one house in 3 hours.  Now if you have seven people working in parallel....

Answer (score 0):

Let $t$ the time a single person needs to build one house. So, the power of a single person is $P=\frac{1}{t}$. From the initial data we have:
$$
3\cdot\frac{1}{t}=\frac{3}{3}=1\Rightarrow t=3 h
$$
Now if $x$ is the time needed by the $7$ people to build $7$ houses, we get:
$$
7\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{7}{x}\Rightarrow x=3h
$$
**P.S.:** There are two implicit assumptions here: *(a).* Each persons work at the same rate (power) with everybody else, *(b).*  Power is "additive", in the sense that: $ \ \frac{W_A}{t_A}+\frac{W_B}{t_B}=\frac{W_{AB}}{t_{AB}}$

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can remember is $\frac{\text{LABOR}\times\text{TIME}}{\text{JOBS}}$ stays constant. Because $\text{LABOR}\times\text{TIME}$ is the work done and work per job doesn't change. Thus $$\frac{\text{LABOR}_1\times\text{TIME}_1}{\text{JOBS}_1}=\frac{\text{LABOR}_2\times\text{TIME}_2}{\text{JOBS}_2}$$
and in this case
$$\frac{3\times3}{3}=\frac{7\times x}{7}$$